# Which grammar form is in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

Which grammar form is in the sentence bellow?
'You are finally graduated.'

Comment: Use citations in answers, if you please. This does not appear to answer the question.

Comment: Putting aside the fact that native speakers would normally say *You **have** finally graduated,* it's syntactically much the same as, say, *We are now free* (Subject + Verb + Adverb + Adjective). Assuming you're happy to classify the past participle ***graduated*** as an "adjectival" usage in your cited context.

Comment: Thank you, I just wish to ask, could this also be Present Simple Passive?

Comment: Kate, could you rephrase that to take account of FumbleFingers' Comment, please?